# How do I setup my react/redux/express app on my shared hosting server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So I built my first react application using create-react-app with Node.js and Express. Locally I run port 5000 for my API which is 'api/searches' (just the one endpoint) and the main react application on port 3000 using concurrently.

I'm trying to get it running on my shared hosting. I SSH into my server, got node and NPM installed. I run the 'npm run build' script to create the dist folder and uploaded that to a directory on the server. The HTML on the website DOES render, but my API is not active and there might be other issues so it has no functionality at this point. How do I finish this setup? I don't really know what is broken?

I also am using redux and don't really know a lot about it so not sure if that's also an issue. My application at his point is basically one form hooked up to my mongoDB with mLab. Actually a slight modification to this GitHub project here:

**https://github.com/bradtraversy/mern_shopping_list**

In the browser console I see:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () - /api/searches:1
```

This is my main package.json file

```
{
  "name": "name goes here",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.6",
    "nightmare": "^3.0.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.7",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  }
}
```

This is my package.json file inside my client folder:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.3.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "homepage": "https://www.example.com/myapp/" <- this is how I got it working on my server I think?
}
```

Comment: Can You paste logs from express application? I saw that You wrote const port = process.env.PORT || 5000, so the problem can be here. What does proess.env.PORT means - pick whatever is in the environment variable PORT, or 3000 if there's nothing there. That is the known problem in some hosting services since port is set by them (Heroku for example).

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the logs you're referring to? I think the port is one of the issues I'm having but I don't fully understand.

Comment: Do You use Heroku? I see Heroku postinstall command in package.json. I mean application logs (backend). In the code I am able to see some console.log(...), I asked for the output of those commands.

Comment: As I stated in the question I am using shared hosting, not Heroku. The script was from the repo and does work on Heroku, but I want my app hosted on my own server.

Comment: OK, so can You provide logs from the backend application (especially startup logs) . If it is linux based server: 'node server.js > log.txt' and then 'cat log.txt'

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. As of right now I 'bundled' my app and uploaded the dist directory that was created to the server. Should I have my entire application on the server instead?